# Tinymce - How can I specify a directory on my server to use when I insert an image?

Tags: tinymce

This works fine if I was to implement uploading an image via tinymce etc, which I'm really not interested in doing.

I already have hundreds of images uploaded from another part of the website that I'd like to insert into pages being edited and created with tinymce v5.

But how can I indicate in the Insert/Edit dialog box to show just the contents of one directory on the server?

I had a hack from vers 3 something I think it was that I can't locate, and it being so ancient I'm sure it's pretty useless, it didn't even support Safari, so it had to be 10+ years old.

Can't find anything in tinymce docs about indicating a directory to use with insert image.

Some custom javascript to include somewhere???

My basic starter tinymce code:

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
selector: '#editor',

plugins: 'image code',

toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',

/* enable title field in the Image dialog*/
image_title: true,
/* enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs*/
automatic_uploads: true,

/*
URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file- 
image-upload/#images_upload_url)
images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
*/
file_picker_types: 'image',

/* and here's our custom image picker*/
file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

/*
Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without
even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
once you do not need it anymore.
*/

input.onchange = function () {
var file = this.files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
/*
Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
*/
var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
blobCache.add(blobInfo);

/* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);   
};

input.click();
},
content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }' 
});
</strict>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do so:

1. [MoxieManager](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/moxiemanager/) plugin. [Here is the demo](https://www.moxiemanager.com/demos/tinymce.php). However, it's a premium feature.
2. Depends on the number of images you have on the server. If there aren't many, you can try to use the `image_list` option of the [Image plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/image/#image_list). It will load the editor with a predefined set of images.
3. Implement the custom file picker with the [`file_picker_callback`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/image/#file_picker_callback) option.